# GridView.Sort using JavaScript (no jQuery or any plugins)?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

<%# XPath("ID")%>
                    
                
                
                    
                        <%# XPath("PQR")%>
                    
                
                
                    
                        <%# XPath("XYZ")%>

I have dropdown with list of id and need to show data only for that id in GridView using pure JavaScript without using any plugins or code behind file, no jQuery.
How can I do with JavaScript.
Thanks

Comment: i have tried,i can able to display using table.. but i want it in GridView. I can only see jquery in all sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First specify javascript function to run on selection change for drop down list:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" onchange="filterGrid(this.value);">
```

Then write logic in filterGrid js function:

```
function filterGrid(value)
    {
        var grid = document.getElementById('<%= GridView1.ClientID %>');

        if (grid != null)
        {
            var rows = grid.getElementsByTagName("tr");

            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; ++i)
            {
                var cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td");

                if (cells.length > 0)
                {
                    if (cells[IndexOfColumnWithId].innerText === value)
                        rows[i].style.display = 'table-row';
                    else
                        rows[i].style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Replace 'IndexOfColumnWithId' in above code with integer value of id column index from your grid.